# How to see Google Analytics measurement protocol (debugging) through logcat or terminal in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics, adb, google-tag-manager

I have some issues about debugging Google Analytics Measurement Protocol through Android Studio, not so long ago I can use these commands:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [-your app name-]

adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG  
adb logcat -v time -s GAv4
```

But now I cant do it anymore, is there any different way of doing it?

Usually the command lines above you can see log for enhanced ecommerce for GA such as:

> Hit delivery requested: ht=1566372488197, _s=427, _v=ma18.3.85, a=563086223, adid=0e23f1fe-0bd9-45ab-9d4c-a059d6d55616, aid=app.myApp, aiid=com.android.vending, an=Moon, ate=1, av=32, cid=c9af35e1-2b9e-4785-b2d7-ab28acebb764, ea=Product Click, ec=Ecommerce, ni=false, pa=click, pal=New Product, pr1br=D & F, pr1ca=, pr1id=4792115, pr1nm=Gundam Exia, pr1pr=319920.0, pr1ps=0, sr=720x1280, t=event, tid=UA-128510179-8, ul=en-us, v=1

Showing that the Google Analytics is actually receiving the data correctly.

Now all I can see is this message in android studio:

> 19-09-05 17:34:29.462 3117-19610/? W/GAv4-SVC: Network compressed POST connection error: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "ssl.google-analytics.com": No address associated with hostname

with ssl.google-analytics.com unresolved I don't think Charles proxy would work either.

Comment: The correct measurement protocol debug endpoint is https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect.   I cant see what your using.  BTW masurment protocol has nothing to do with firebase or firebase analytics.   Think you should remove those tags.

Comment: How do you usually debug GA V5 (with firebase) from android studio? tags removed.